# node.js jade template - custom syntax and replacements?

Tags: templates, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to get jade to automatically generate urls for me:

so if I have a user link like this:

```
.userLink
  a(href="/#{user}") #{user}
```

I want to be able to replace it with something like (hypothetical syntax):

```
.userLink
  userLink(#{user})
```

Anyway to do this?

Thanks

Edit: OKAY I got it:

```
mixin userLink(user)
  a(href="/" + user)= user

mixin userLink("Bob")
```

Seems like that will work.

Comment: Nice!  Glad you got the glitches worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

Here's a version using jade mixins.  Sadly, I can't seem to find the "user" variable within  the parenthesized attributes list of the "a" tag.

```
mixin userLink(user)
  a(href="/" + user)= user

mixin userLink("Bob")
mixin userLink("Alice")
mixin userLink("Cooper")
```

Generates this HTML

```
<a href="/undefined"></a> Bob
<a href="/undefined"></a> Alice
<a href="/undefined"></a> Cooper
```

---

Just put a helper function into your locals object and call it from the template

```
locals = {userLink: function(userName) { return "<a href=....."}}

jade.render('myview', {locals: locals})
```

Then in your jade template do:

```
= userLink(user)
```

You may also want to look at possibly registering a [dynamicHelper function](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app.dynamichelpers%28%29).

Comment: I'm using jadevu and jade on the client side, so that's not really a good option for me. I also want to keep templating stuff in the jade, rather than have it in the JS as well.

Comment: Uh, if "templating stuff" involves functions, it ain't happening.  Code prepares the data, jade spits it into HTML.

Comment: Ah, mixins is a new thing I haven't played around with much.  I'll update my answer, but jade doesn't seem to be referencing the mixin param within the attributes list.